# React.js: Possible to assign useState() outside function component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there any syntax that would allow assigning `useState` outside of the function component? I have tried this so far but it has not worked:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => setStateData("from useEffect"), []);

  return <div className="App">{stateData}</div>;
}

const [stateData, setStateData] = App.useState("default value"); // fails
// const [stateData, setStateData] = App.prototype.useState("default value"); // also fails

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox: [image: Edit objective-worker-qb20h]

Comment: Why you want to do that? `useState` isn't supposed to work that way, maybe you want to do something else and can be done without using `useState` outside a functional component.

Comment: Mostly for my own understanding of how React works, but possibly for code organization if I like the separation.

Comment: Short answer, no, as this is not how React Hooks work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any syntax that would allow assigning useState outside of the function component?

If you take a look at the [docs and Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)

> ## Only Call Hooks from React Functions
>
> **Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.** Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>   ✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).

So... no, you can't use `useState` outside of a functional component.

Comment: From that page, it looks like wrapping the useState() call in another function does it (a "custom hook"). Is that accurate?

Comment: @SeanDezoysa Yes, it becomes a custom hooks, but you can only call custom hooks inside functional components

Answer (score 20):

Disclaimer: This is an **anti-pattern**¹. If you wanna share state [there's better ways](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components), but just for info…

You can use the `useState`'s `update` function outside of a component by assigning it to a variable. Just be sure to clear it when the component unmounts.

```js
/* Reference to hold the update function */
let updateOutside

function App() {
  const [state, update] = useState()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    /* Assign update to outside variable */
    updateOutside = update

    /* Unassign when component unmounts */
    return () => updateOutside = null
  })

  return `App State: ${state}`
}

if (updateOutside) updateOutside(/* will re-render App */)
```

¹This code is an anti-pattern as it violates the principles of React's data flow by using a global variable to store a state update function, which can lead to unpredictable behavior and make the code harder to maintain and debug. Instead, it's recommended to use React's built-in mechanisms for managing state and passing data between components, such as props and context.

Comment: Is there any documentation or article explaining in detail why this is an anti-pattern?

Comment: @CùĐứcHiếu Good question. The official docs say specifically to ["Only Call Hooks from React Functions"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). Other than that, it just doesn't seem intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use useState outside of components think about using https://jotai.org/

It's useState replacement with some additional bonuses

```
 import { atom, useAtom } from 'jotai'

// Create your atoms and derivatives
const textAtom = atom('hello')
const uppercaseAtom = atom(
  (get) => get(textAtom).toUpperCase()
)

// Use them anywhere in your app
const Input = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useAtom(textAtom)
  const handleChange = (e) => setText(e.target.value)
  return (
    <input value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
  )
}

const Uppercase = () => {
  const [uppercase] = useAtom(uppercaseAtom)
  return (
    <div>Uppercase: {uppercase}</div>
  )
}

// Now you have the components
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Input />
      <Uppercase />
    </>
  )
}
```