# How to call a function in another component from a different component in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I having two files header.js and upload.js. In upload.js I have a popup modal which should be open  when I click upload button in the header.js

So basically I want to call setOpened function present in upload.js from header.js

header.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
          <Link
             data-bs-toggle="modal"
             onClick={() => setOpened(true)}
             role="button"
            >Upload</Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

upload.js

```
import React from 'react'
const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);

const Upload = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        opened={opened}
        onClose={() => setOpened(false)}
        title="Introduce yourself!"
      >
        {/* Modal content */}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Upload
```

In App.js

```
import Header from './component/Header';
import Footer from './component/Footer';
import Upload from './component/Upload';

function App() {
  return (
   <Header/>
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/upload" element={<Upload/>}/>
       </Routes>
   <Footer/>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is upload.js used only for the purpose of displaying a modal?

Comment: Not Exactly. It having more functionalities also.

Comment: just lift state up or use context or use some state management tool(redux, mobx)
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: You can't call `const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);` from outside the component, that would mean it will only be created once, not matter how many `Upload` components you instantiate [but it's not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59361561/227299). It should be in the function itself.

Comment: Ok Thank You, I have to try another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To echo @I-vasilich-I's comment about [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), you should move your modal open state to a higher level (like in `App`) and pass that state to each child that needs it.

For example

```
const Header = ({ openModal }) => (
  <div>
    <Link data-bs-toggle="modal" onClick={openModal} role="button">
      Upload
    </Link>
  </div>
);

const Upload = ({ opened, closeModal }) => (
  <div>
    <Modal opened={opened} onClose={closeModal} title="Introduce yourself!">
      {/* Modal content */}
    </Modal>
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Header openModal={() => setOpened(true)} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/upload" element={<Upload opened={opened} closeModal={() => setOpened(false)} />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

(note make sure you add imports)